# Xamarin Android Memory - Strict Mode instances=2; limit=1

Tags: android, xamarin, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

I've checked out some other posts on this subject but haven't found the answer I am looking for yet.  I'm trying to evaluate memory usage in a few Xamarin Android applications and have gotten myself fairly confused on the subject.

For my own benefit, I am using the most basic app I can for this initial test.  There are two activities.  The first activity has a button that launches the second activity.  I then click the hardware back button and I go back to the first activity.  I'll post the code, but that is all there is to it.

I've added:

```
        var builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        var policy = builder.DetectActivityLeaks().PenaltyLog().Build();
        StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(policy);
```

Inside of the OnCreate of both of my activities to try and see any violations or if the activities are leaking.  What i'm observing is overtime I click the back button from the second activity, I get a console output

> [StrictMode] class md5774612d1059550a86887b889cb974a69.SecondActivity; instances=2; limit=1
>   [StrictMode] android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class md5774612d1059550a86887b889cb974a69.SecondActivity; instances=2; limit=1
>   [StrictMode]    at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)

This will continue to increase "instances" each time I load the next activity and hit the back button again.  I don't understand why there are multiple instances in existence.  Is it just because the Garbage collector hasn't taken the time to clean up the previous activities?  Or do I really have a memory leak of activities even in this simple application?  If I call System.GC.Collect() in the onResume of the screens, I no longer see the multiple instance violations.  Obviously I don't want to be telling the garbage collector when to do its job, so if the issue is just that it hasn't gotten around to it yet I think that is ok?  But is there any better practices I should be following to ensure my activities release all of the memory?  Thank you for any advice.

Code for the two activities below.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace Test.Droid
{
[Activity (Label = "Test.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        var builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        var policy = builder.DetectActivityLeaks().PenaltyLog().Build();
        StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(policy);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        //System.GC.Collect();
    }
}
}
```

Second Activity

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
namespace Test.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "Test.Droid")]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    public SecondActivity()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        var policy = builder.DetectActivityLeaks().PenaltyLog().Build();
        StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(policy);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };      }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Don't keep activities** in the Developer options to force ART/Dalvik to clean up activities as soon as possible for testing.

[image]

*Personally*, I use `GC.Collect` in many spots to force Mono (and thus ART/Dalvik) to sweep memory. Most of those are related to Images/Bitmaps that traverse the Java/C# Bridge and you end up with a bitmap that is "living" in both VMs and thus consuming double the memory...

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/